# Addin 0 in front of one digit number/text in bash script

Tags: bash

I would like to compare a number, which is the output of a command, with a constant and do some manipulation. That is, if `$id < 10`, I want to see `590$id` and if it is above 10, I want to see `59$id`.

I found that `expr` doesn't working here:

```
ID=3
NUM=59$ID
if [ `expr $ID` -lt 10]; then
   NUM=590$ID
fi
echo $NUM
```

The output of the code is `593` and not `5903`. Even, `$(($ID + 5900)) -lt 5910` writes `593`.

How can I fix that?

Comment: There are syntax issues. You may use: `(( $ID < 10 )) && NUM="590$ID"`

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash
ID=$(printf "%02d" 3 )
##NUM=59$ID  ##Commented this to check if, condition is getting satisfied or not. Doesn't seem to be fit here.
(( $ID < 10 )) && NUM="59$ID"
echo "$NUM"
```

Output will be `5903` after running above code.

Comment: @mahmood, Could you please do let me know if this helps you?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `expr`. It's old and tricky.

Don't use backticks `. They are [discouraged](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete) and `$( ... )` is preferred.

For arithmetic comparisons use [arithmetic expansions](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression). Just

```
if (( ID < 10 )); then
```

Note that bash is space aware and your script has a syntax error, it is missing a space - the `10];` should be `10 ];`.

Note that by convention uppercase variables should be used for exported variables.

Looking at your code I think you just want:

```
NUM=$((5900 + ID))
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting to five digit number:

```
printf "%05d" $1
```

Adding newline symbol:

```
printf "%05d\n" $1
```

Try it:

```
for i in `seq 1 9 109`; do printf "%03d\n" $i; done
```